# Maximum code words

Tags: coding-theory

i am new to coding theory. i am trying to understand some of the basics by solving a few questions. I came across this one. Assuming $\\C$ is a binary (not necessarily linear) code of length $\\n$ and minimum hamming distance $\\d$. Atmost how many codewords can $\\C$ have? *Give an example to the extremal case*. I am stuck at the example part. i think using the fact that 
$\left|C\right|\times \sum _{r=0}^e^nC_r\le 2^n$ - am i right?
I dont know what to do about the example part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [sphere packing bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_bound) says that the number of codewords in a code with length $n$ and distance d over an alphabet of size $q$ is at most $\frac{q^n}{\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{d-1}{2} \rfloor} \binom{n}{k} (q-1)^k}$.

Codes which attain equality are said to be perfect. Examples of perfect codes which are non-trivial are [hamming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code) and [golay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_Golay_code) codes (in fact, the Hamming code, Binary Golay and Ternary Golay are the only parameters you can get for non-trivial perfect codes over a finite field).

Comment: thanks @Batman. I think i got that part. but what can i provide as an example for an extremal case. are perfect codes extremal cases o.O ?

Comment: Yes. Any code has to satisfy the sphere packing bound, so codes which meet it (i.e. perfect codes) are the extremal case.

Comment: Thanks alot @Batman :). That makes it all clear now, by the way, any suggestion or ideas to this one: i have tried a couple of ways but cant get right: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1251996/vector-distance