# Vector distance of binary

Tags: coding-theory, information-theory

Suppose $\overline{u},\overline{v},\overline{w},\overline{x}$ are four binary vectors, pairwise distance d apart. Show that d must be even, there's exactly one vector which is a distance $d\over 2$ from each of $\overline{u},\overline{v},\overline{w}$ and there's atmost one vector which is at a distance $d\over 2$ from each of $\overline{u},\overline{v},\overline{w},\overline{x}$.

I know that i have to use the triangular inequality somewhere and perhaps i only need three of the vectors-and may be let them be equidistant...- but i got no idea how to apply it or proceed with the proof. Any suggestions, ideas are welcome. it could be text for reading. Thanks alot.

Comment: Hint: You probably know that with the Hamming metric in $\{0,1\}^n$ the triangle inequality can only fail to be an equality by an even amount!

Comment: yes, we are to assume that they are binary vectors. Let me add that in the question right away. I dont get what you mean in the hint

Comment: In the binary Hamming space we have (in addition to the triangle inequality)
$$d(\overline{a},\overline{c})\equiv d(\overline{a},\overline{b})+d(\overline{b},\overline{c})\pmod 2.$$ Can you see why?

Comment: woow, it is true, but i dont know why? i have checked it on some examples. but i cant figure out why.

Comment: The positions where $\bar{b}$ disagrees with both $\bar{a}$ and $\bar{c}$ contribute a two to the sum on the r.h.s. of that congruence and a zero to the l.h.s. The remaining positions contribute equally to both sides.

Comment: Yes. that is true :) - but i dont see how that forces d to be even.

Comment: Try it with $\bar a = \bar u$, $\bar b =\bar v$ and $\bar c =\bar w$.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, but now my holiday and weekend starts today, so am back on my coding theory and optimization-question-solving spree. Well, if you put it that way, it becomes evidently clear that d is even :). so the hardest part was figuring out that the triangular inequality was transformed that way for binary hamming spaces. thanks really :). because assuming they are all d apart, then definitely turns out to be even. ok, another hint- also a good and indirect as the previous one on how to prove that $d \over 2 $ part. am fired up now. am not sleeping tonight :)

Comment: hi, i can't accept a comment. can you make it an answer so that i can accept it?