# Linearity of codes

Tags: coding-theory, information-theory

Assuming $C$ is a binary linear code and let $a$ $\notin $ $C$ be any vector. Show that $C$ $\cup  (a + C) $ is also linear.

I know that for any $C_1,C_2 \in C $ then $\alpha C_1 + \beta C_2 \in C$ but now how do i apply this to this situation? Is it even the right way to go about this problem? All suggestions and ideas are deeply appreciated. thanks

Comment: Take $C_1, C_2\in \mathcal C\cup(a+\mathcal C)$. You want to prove that $\forall \alpha, \beta\in \{0,1\}\left(\alpha C_1+\beta C_2\in  \mathcal C\cup(a+\mathcal C)\right)$. Consider the case $C_1, C_2\in \mathcal C$, the case $C_1, C_2\in a+\mathcal C$ and the case $C_1\in C$ and $C_2\in a+\mathcal C$.

Comment: ok, i think i did not understand the last case. Why take them separately?
Anyway, let me try it first. Thanks. If something uncertain comes up, i will let you know.

Comment: Now i get it :). thanks. can you make this an answer so that i can accept it?

Comment: I'd prefer if you posted a detailed answer yourself.

Comment: Alright, but it's going to take me a while to get all the formatting right :).
Meanwhile can you take a look at this for me as well. Still ideas such as these are the best :). I have solved about 25 questions in the last 8 hours but two more are left. Am not quite sure what to do. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1251996/vector-distance
i know i should  force them to be equidistant somewhere, then use * **triangular inequality** *. but cant see how to start or even proceed.

Comment: is this ok @Git Gud ?

Comment: Sorry, was too lazy and busy to read until now. I think you're thinking correctly, but you didn't write things appropriately. For instance in the last case, since $C_2\in a+\mathcal C$, there exists $u\in \mathcal C$ such that $C_2=a+u$. So $$\alpha C_1+\beta C_2=\alpha C_1+\beta(a+u)=\beta a+(\alpha C_1+\beta u).$$ Now if $\beta=0$, then only $\alpha C_1$ survives and this is in $\mathcal C\color{grey}{\subseteq \mathcal C\cup a+\mathcal C}$. And if $\beta=1$, then you have $a+(\alpha C_1+u)$ which is $a+\mathcal C$. Similarly for the other cases.

Comment: oh, ok. got it then :).

Comment: well, i admit that yours is more "elegant", but i think the values dont change. say if $ \beta $ is $ 0 $    in my case as well, only $ \alpha C_1 $ will survive .   actually i was also off, but since its weekend, am going to emback on my coding theory and optimization-question-solving spree :). so no hard feelings there. infact thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In brief, Considering the cases clearly stipulated by @Git Gud, First taking
 $C_1, C_2 \in C$ then we have

> $\alpha C_1 + \beta C_2 \cup a + \alpha C_1 + \beta C_2 \forall \alpha,\beta\in { 0,1} $.

Clearly the left part of the $ \cup$ sign is $\in C $ and the right part is $\in a + C $

Next, taking $C_1,C_2 \in a + C$ it follows that;

> $C \cup  \alpha (a + C_1 + C_2 ) + \beta (a +  C_1 + C_2 ) $

the right part of the $\cup$ is in $ a + C $ hence the union holds $ \forall \alpha , \beta \in 0,1 $

finally, taking $ C_1 \in C,C_2 \in a + C $ we get;

> $\alpha C_1 + \beta (a + C_2) \in C \cup (a + C) $ definitely and we are done.